# Not return result with in-app purchase in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

**Hi All,**

i have a problem with in-app purchase last week, can't solve it and never got it before.(
current i use swift and xcode 6.1)

My problem is: ( test in sanbox mode and still not uploaded appstore any version yet )

- The first time purchase itn't return state .Purchased ( success
  purchase ) ( but when hit second time it return .Restored ( had
  purchased))
- purchase return failed many time ( can not connect Itune
  store but still purchase --> maybe sabox mode ?)

Here My code:

```
func fetchAvailableProducts() {

    let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.produto_value);

    let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);

    productsRequest.delegate = self;

    productsRequest.start();

}

func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

    var count : Int = response.products.count

    if (count>0) {

        var validProducts = response.products

         validProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct

        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.produto_value) {

            println(validProduct.localizedTitle)

            println(validProduct.localizedDescription)

            println(validProduct.price)

            purchaseMyProduct()

        } else {

            println(validProduct.productIdentifier)

        }

    } else {

        println("nothing")

    }

}



func canMakePurchases() -> Bool

{

    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()

}



func purchaseMyProduct() {

    if (self.canMakePurchases() && validProduct != nil) {

        println("Purchases are allowed ...")

        var payment: SKPayment = SKPayment(product: validProduct)

        var defaultQueue: SKPaymentQueue  = SKPaymentQueue ()

        defaultQueue.addTransactionObserver(self)

        defaultQueue.addPayment(payment)

    } else {



var alert = UIAlertController(title: "MyApp", message:stringLocate.getString("PURCHASE_FAILED"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        blackScreenTopConstraint.constant = 3000

    }

}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)    {

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {

        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{

            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Restored:

                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)

                isPro = true

                blackScreenTopConstraint.constant = 3000

                updateMyLayout()

                break;

            case .Purchased:

                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)

                isPro = true

                blackScreenTopConstraint.constant = 3000

                updateMyLayout()

                break;

            case .Deferred:

var alert = UIAlertController(title: "MyApp", message:stringLocate.getString("PURCHASE_FAILED"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)



                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                blackScreenTopConstraint.constant = 3000 

               break

            case .Failed:

var alert = UIAlertController(title: "MyApp", message:stringLocate.getString("PURCHASE_FAILED"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)



                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                blackScreenTopConstraint.constant = 3000

                break;

            default:

                break;

            }

        }

    }



}
```

Have anybody got that problem, help me solve it, 
Many thanks!.

Comment: are you testing in simulator..???

Comment: Thanks Anil, Im testing on real devices.

Comment: this is a common problem of sandbox mode when you tried in app like first message that " cannot connect to Applestore or itunes "..if you retry the purchase has success message and parallel message that "" cannot connct to itunes ".

Comment: I think it too, but my problem focus on it not return success state, but still success because the second time hit purchase it return "Restored" state mean had purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For restoring inApp purchases consider these points.
1. Non consumables must implement restore functionality. 
2. You need to add delegate function for SKPaymentQueue.

```
 func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue:SKPaymentQueue!)
{

    for transaction:AnyObject in queue.transactions
    {
        let trans : SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction
        var identifier : NSString = trans.payment.productIdentifier
//            println(identifier)
}
```

Comment: Your english is too good for me. I cannot understand what you are saying. If you have bought an in-app than you should restore it not buy it again. Once you bought anything you should unlock or do whatever desired.

Comment: I solve problem by using MKStoreKit, maybe it's happen because i use swift , have no idea, thanks for your anwser Omer.

Comment: Its not issue of Swift. I am using Swift for inApps. Anyways good for you that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Have anybody got my issued, i had release version on appstore but it's still happend, when user hit purchase show nothing but when hit again it return purchase!